# Woocommerce new order email notification to admin for "On Hold" orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

In WooCommerce, when a customer goes to checkout from cart and submit the order, my woocommerce is set to place order on-hold until authorized by the admin, but right now if the order is set to "on-hold" the Admin doesn't received any email about.

I would like to send an email to Admin when a customer places a new order on hold. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

The following will send the new order email notification to admin, when an order status is on-hold:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'email_on_hold_order_admin_notification', 10, 2 );
function email_on_hold_order_admin_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

> **Note:** The "new order" email notification need to be enabled in Woocommerce admin settings.

---

> **Since WooCommerce 5+:** [Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66604256/allow-re-sending-new-order-notification-in-woocommerce-5/66604522#66604522)