# Allow re-sending New Order Notification in WooCommerce 5+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

I've been using the following snippet without any issues. For no reason that I can think of it stopped being triggered today.

Could it perhaps be written better?

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'email_completed_order_admin_notification', 10, 2 );
function email_completed_order_admin_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_New_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't been paying attention. I'll create the thread on the WooCommerce plugin support page. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Found the way and works now back again.

Comment: I have opened an issue, as main hook argument should be set to true by default (as mentioned on the comment bloc), should allow by default to resend New Order Notification: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/29367

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 5.0 [a new filter hook has been added](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/emails/class-wc-email-new-order.php#L99-L107), that disables resending "New Order" email notification, restricting this specific notification to be sent only one time.

This is what has been added to `WC_Email_New_Order` `trigger()` method *(default is set to `false`)*:

```
/**
 * Controls if new order emails can be resend multiple times.
 *
 * @since 5.0.0
 * @param bool $allows Defaults to true.
 */
if ( 'true' === $email_already_sent && ! apply_filters( 'woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', false ) ) {
    return;
}
```

So you need now to add this little additional piece of code, to unlock this notification:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_order_email_allows_resend', '__return_true' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Now your code will work again.

> I have [opened an issue on WooCommerce Github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/29367), as main hook argument should be set to `true` by default (as mentioned on the comment bloc), and should allow by default to resend New Order Notification.

Comment: The aforementioned issue was closed without behaviour changes. WooCommerce staff confirmed that sending notification email to customer just once is the intended behaviour.